# Sorting Python list contating dicts

Tags: python, dictionary

I am looking for the fastest way to re-factor that following list which contains dicts as items

```
[{u'domain': u'1d663096.bestapp243.biz',
  u'flag_char_code': u'DR',
  u'flag_hex': u'8081',
  u'identifier': u'0000000002264A00',
  u'indicator': u'Snd',
  u'ip': u'172.30.133.105',
  u'proto': u'UDP',
  u'r_q': u'R Q',
  u'raw': u'10/12/2014 11:20:27 AM 1114 PACKET  0000000002264A00 UDP Snd 172.30.133.105  aba2 R Q [8081   DR  NOERROR] A      .1d663096.bestapp243.biz.',
  u'record': u'A',
  u'status': u'NOERROR',
  u'thread_id': u'1114',
  u'timestamp': u'2014-10-12T11:20:27',
  u'xid': u'aba2'},
 {u'domain': u'1d663096.bestapp243.biz',
  u'flag_char_code': u'DR',
  u'flag_hex': u'8081',
  u'identifier': u'0000000002264A00',
  u'indicator': u'Snd',
  u'ip': u'172.30.133.105',
  u'proto': u'UDP',
  u'r_q': u'R Q',
  u'raw': u'10/12/2014 11:20:27 AM 1114 PACKET  0000000002264A00 UDP Snd 172.30.133.105  aba2 R Q [8081   DR  NOERROR] A      .1d663096.bestapp243.biz.',
  u'record': u'A',
  u'status': u'NOERROR',
  u'thread_id': u'1114',
  u'timestamp': u'2014-10-12T11:20:27',
  u'xid': u'aba2'},
 {u'domain': u'mgames.cf',
  u'flag_char_code': u'DR',
  u'flag_hex': u'8081',
  u'identifier': u'000000000220ED40',
  u'indicator': u'Snd',
  u'ip': u'172.30.138.116',
  u'proto': u'UDP',
  u'r_q': u'R Q',
  u'raw': u'10/13/2014 2:31:46 PM 110C PACKET  000000000220ED40 UDP Snd 172.30.138.116  f957 R Q [8081   DR  NOERROR] A      .mgames.cf.',
  u'record': u'A',
  u'status': u'NOERROR',
  u'thread_id': u'110C',
  u'timestamp': u'2014-10-13T14:31:46',
  u'xid': u'f957'},
  {u'domain': u'google.com',
  u'flag_char_code': u'DR',
  u'flag_hex': u'8081',
  u'identifier': u'0000000002264A00',
  u'indicator': u'Snd',
  u'ip': u'172.30.133.105',
  u'proto': u'UDP',
  u'r_q': u'R Q',
  u'raw': u'10/12/2014 11:20:27 AM 1114 PACKET  0000000002264A00 UDP Snd 172.30.133.105  aba2 R Q [8081   DR  NOERROR] A      .google.com.',
  u'record': u'A',
  u'status': u'NOERROR',
  u'thread_id': u'1114',
  u'timestamp': u'2014-10-12T11:20:27',
  u'xid': u'aba2'},
 {u'domain': u'qwe.domainsworkingsdromms.com',
  u'flag_char_code': u'DR',
  u'flag_hex': u'8381',
  u'identifier': u'030E8D88',
  u'indicator': u'Snd',
  u'ip': u'172.27.29.77',
  u'proto': u'UDP',
  u'r_q': u'R Q',
  u'raw': u'10/14/2014 10:37:13 AM 17E0 PACKET  030E8D88 UDP Snd 172.27.29.77    80eb R Q [8381   DR NXDOMAIN] A     .qwe.domainsworkingsdromms.com.',
  u'record': u'A',
  u'status': u'NXDOMAIN',
  u'thread_id': u'17E0',
  u'timestamp': u'2014-10-14T10:37:13',
  u'xid': u'80eb'}]
```

to output something like:

```
{
  '172.30.133.105': {
    '1d663096.bestapp243.biz':
      [
        {u'domain': u'1d663096.bestapp243.biz',
          u'flag_char_code': u'DR',
          u'flag_hex': u'8081',
          u'identifier': u'0000000002264A00',
          u'indicator': u'Snd',
          u'ip': u'172.30.133.105',
          u'proto': u'UDP',
          u'r_q': u'R Q',
          u'raw': u'10/12/2014 11:20:27 AM 1114 PACKET  0000000002264A00 UDP Snd 172.30.133.105  aba2 R Q [8081   DR  NOERROR] A      .1d663096.bestapp243.biz.',
          u'record': u'A',
          u'status': u'NOERROR',
          u'thread_id': u'1114',
          u'timestamp': u'2014-10-12T11:20:27',
          u'xid': u'aba2'},
        {u'domain': u'1d663096.bestapp243.biz',
          u'flag_char_code': u'DR',
          u'flag_hex': u'8081',
          u'identifier': u'0000000002264A00',
          u'indicator': u'Snd',
          u'ip': u'172.30.133.105',
          u'proto': u'UDP',
          u'r_q': u'R Q',
          u'raw': u'10/12/2014 11:20:27 AM 1114 PACKET  0000000002264A00 UDP Snd 172.30.133.105  aba2 R Q [8081   DR  NOERROR] A      .1d663096.bestapp243.biz.',
          u'record': u'A',
          u'status': u'NOERROR',
          u'thread_id': u'1114',
          u'timestamp': u'2014-10-12T11:20:27',
          u'xid': u'aba2'},
      ],
    'google.com':
      [
        {u'domain': u'google.com',
        u'flag_char_code': u'DR',
        u'flag_hex': u'8081',
        u'identifier': u'0000000002264A00',
        u'indicator': u'Snd',
        u'ip': u'172.30.133.105',
        u'proto': u'UDP',
        u'r_q': u'R Q',
        u'raw': u'10/12/2014 11:20:27 AM 1114 PACKET  0000000002264A00 UDP Snd 172.30.133.105  aba2 R Q [8081   DR  NOERROR] A      .google.com.',
        u'record': u'A',
        u'status': u'NOERROR',
        u'thread_id': u'1114',
        u'timestamp': u'2014-10-12T11:20:27',
        u'xid': u'aba2'}
      ]
  },
  '172.30.138.116': {
    'mgames.cf': 
      [
       {u'domain': u'mgames.cf',
        u'flag_char_code': u'DR',
        u'flag_hex': u'8081',
        u'identifier': u'000000000220ED40',
        u'indicator': u'Snd',
        u'ip': u'172.30.138.116',
        u'proto': u'UDP',
        u'r_q': u'R Q',
        u'raw': u'10/13/2014 2:31:46 PM 110C PACKET  000000000220ED40 UDP Snd 172.30.138.116  f957 R Q [8081   DR  NOERROR] A      .mgames.cf.',
        u'record': u'A',
        u'status': u'NOERROR',
        u'thread_id': u'110C',
        u'timestamp': u'2014-10-13T14:31:46',
        u'xid': u'f957'}        
      ]
  }
}
```

Should I divide them into two lists, the 1st one will have ips as keys then iterate over them to fix the domains as keys for the sub dicts ?

Any ideas would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you need to re-factor, know the re-factored structure and do that explicitly

```
foo = {}
for rec in data:
    foo[rec['ip']] = {}
    foo[rec['ip']][rec['domain']] = rec
```

**Note**, if you are not to orthodox in using `dict` and rather open for `defaultdict`, `autovivication` can work wonder here

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> def tree(): return defaultdict(tree) 
>>> foo = tree()
>>> for rec in data:
    foo[rec['ip']][rec['domain']] = rec
```

**Example**

```
>>> import pprint
>>> pprint.pprint(foo)
{u'172.27.29.77': {u'qwe.domainsworkingsdromms.com': {u'domain': u'qwe.domainsworkingsdromms.com',
                                                      u'flag_char_code': u'DR',
                                                      u'flag_hex': u'8381',
                                                      u'identifier': u'030E8D88',
                                                      u'indicator': u'Snd',
                                                      u'ip': u'172.27.29.77',
                                                      u'proto': u'UDP',
                                                      u'r_q': u'R Q',
                                                      u'raw': u'10/14/2014 10:37:13 AM 17E0 PACKET  030E8D88 UDP Snd 172.27.29.77    80eb R Q [8381   DR NXDOMAIN] A     .qwe.domainsworkingsdromms.com.',
                                                      u'record': u'A',
                                                      u'status': u'NXDOMAIN',
                                                      u'thread_id': u'17E0',
                                                      u'timestamp': u'2014-10-14T10:37:13',
                                                      u'xid': u'80eb'}},
 u'172.30.133.105': {u'google.com': {u'domain': u'google.com',
                                     u'flag_char_code': u'DR',
                                     u'flag_hex': u'8081',
                                     u'identifier': u'0000000002264A00',
                                     u'indicator': u'Snd',
                                     u'ip': u'172.30.133.105',
                                     u'proto': u'UDP',
                                     u'r_q': u'R Q',
                                     u'raw': u'10/12/2014 11:20:27 AM 1114 PACKET  0000000002264A00 UDP Snd 172.30.133.105  aba2 R Q [8081   DR  NOERROR] A      .google.com.',
                                     u'record': u'A',
                                     u'status': u'NOERROR',
                                     u'thread_id': u'1114',
                                     u'timestamp': u'2014-10-12T11:20:27',
                                     u'xid': u'aba2'}},
 u'172.30.138.116': {u'mgames.cf': {u'domain': u'mgames.cf',
                                    u'flag_char_code': u'DR',
                                    u'flag_hex': u'8081',
                                    u'identifier': u'000000000220ED40',
                                    u'indicator': u'Snd',
                                    u'ip': u'172.30.138.116',
                                    u'proto': u'UDP',
                                    u'r_q': u'R Q',
                                    u'raw': u'10/13/2014 2:31:46 PM 110C PACKET  000000000220ED40 UDP Snd 172.30.138.116  f957 R Q [8081   DR  NOERROR] A      .mgames.cf.',
                                    u'record': u'A',
                                    u'status': u'NOERROR',
                                    u'thread_id': u'110C',
                                    u'timestamp': u'2014-10-13T14:31:46',
                                    u'xid': u'f957'}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all I could able to do it:

Here is the solution:

```
ips_as_keys = {}
domains_as_sub_keys = {}
for i in ES_result:
    if i.get('ip') not in ips_as_keys:
        if i.get('domain') not in domains_as_sub_keys:
            domains_as_sub_keys[i.get('domain')] = [i]
        else:
            domains_as_sub_keys[i.get('domain')].append(i)
        ips_as_keys[i.get('ip')] = [domains_as_sub_keys]
    else:
        ips_as_keys[i.get('ip')].append(domains_as_sub_keys)
```